# Google PageSpeed Issue

Tags: google-pagespeed

`error I get:`

```
Minify JavaScript
Compacting JavaScript code can save many bytes of data and speed up downloading, parsing, and execution time.
Minify JavaScript for the following resources to reduce their size by 254B (22% reduction).
```

[image: one]

`My file`

[image: two]

My JavaScript file is minified (as you see in second image) but i still get error to Minify it! **what could be possibly wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

JUST Simply Defer or aysnc the javascript file like this

```
<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>
```

all you should be good to go.